# Logback MDC for multithread webservice

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, logback, mdc

I am facing problem to implement MDC for my webservice which has multi entiti-id as input and then this service hits one by one external service. Therefore we created one-thread for each separate entity-id and then collect all the replies.
It's very hard to link the log entry for each transaction from out service to external service.
To address this, I have introduce MDC
 Now, the problem is ,
http request is getting new correlationId but internal thread has stuck with first correlationId.
To implement MDC, I made this filter:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.MDC;

@WebFilter(filterName = "correlationIdFilter", urlPatterns = { "/*" })
public class CorrelationIdFilter implements Filter {
    public static final String DEFAULT_CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME = "requestCorrelationId";
    public static final String INIT_PARM_CORRELATION_ID_HEADER = "correlation.id.header";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CorrelationIdFilter.class);
    private String correlationHeaderName;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String headerName = filterConfig.getInitParameter(INIT_PARM_CORRELATION_ID_HEADER);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(headerName)) {
            correlationHeaderName = DEFAULT_CORRELATION_ID_HEADER_NAME;
        } else {
            correlationHeaderName = headerName.trim();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
            ServletException
    {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String correlationId = httpServletRequest.getHeader(correlationHeaderName);
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(correlationId)) {
            correlationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            MDC.put("correlationId", correlationId);
        }

        LOGGER.info(MDC.get("correlationId"));
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.clear();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
        // NoOp
    }

}
```

Sample Log:

First attempt:

```
[2015-09-11 15:35:05,466] [Default Executor-thread-33][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1111 size  : 357 ms  [2015-09-11 15:35:05,466] [Default Executor-thread-34][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1112 size  : 364 ms  [2015-09-11 15:35:05,468] [Default Executor-thread-17][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1113 size  : 383 ms  [2015-09-11 15:35:05,469] [Default Executor-thread-56][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1114 size  : 395 ms  [2015-09-11 15:35:05,471] [Default Executor-thread-61][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]  -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1115 size  : 369 ms  [2015-09-11 15:35:05,478] [Default Executor-thread-13][DEBUG][Service] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -    Performance of getEntryTotalsPeriod service  for 5 Entities   : 9986 ms
```

Second attempt

```
[2015-09-11 15:36:22,616] [Default Executor-thread-34][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1111 size  : 431 ms  [2015-09-11 15:36:22,627] [Default Executor-thread-41][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1112 size  : 427 ms  [2015-09-11 15:36:22,630] [Default Executor-thread-29][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1113 size  : 403 ms  [2015-09-11 15:36:22,634] [Default Executor-thread-16][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1114 size  : 302 ms  [2015-09-11 15:36:22,634] [Default Executor-thread-15][DEBUG][XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX] 941ded25-3041-47e2-915d-48ff65758f8d -     Performance of XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX for one Entity- 1115 size  : 315 ms  [2015-09-11 15:36:22,642] [Default Executor-thread-49][DEBUG][Service] 6360d4c6-5330-4f7d-ac3a-06e5d75f73d5 -    Performance of  service  for 5 Entities   : 5372 ms
```

Last line is from http and which has changed correlationId but not the child multi thread service call that's same correlation id all the time.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Sorry, what does MDC stand for?

Comment: MDC- Mapped Diagnostic Context

Comment: MDC- It's used to link the log entries to trace the complete transaction from end to end. we can differentiate each transaction with client-id,sessionId and session-id can be prepend to all important log entries inside the application log.

Comment: I know of MDC, but I can't understand your problem. It's not clear. Are you loosing the `correlationId` when calling the external service? Are you always getting the same `correlationId`? Do you need the same `correlationId` for every call to the external service? Please further clarify.

Comment: Are you loosing the correlationId when calling the external service? -> i am not loosing the correlationId. Are you always getting the same correlationId?-> Yes, after first time, correlationId is not getting change for multithread part.Do you need the same correlationId for every call to the external service? ->I need same correlationid which was created on http call and all logging should tied up with same transaction correlationid